# How can I get microsoft graph findMeetingTimes working properly?

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

I've been using Microsoft Graph API methods to retrieve Meeting Suggestion Times but the following error's returned rather than the right object:
`"Code: BadArgument\r\nMessage: Invalid user address\r\nInner error:\r\n\tCode: UnsupportedScenario\r\nAdditionalData:\r\n\tdate: 2021-07-01T15:44:10\r\n\trequest-id: fbb7587c-356f-4e96-80b5-7a684069df79\r\n\tclient-request-id: fbb7587c-356f-4e96-80b5-7a684069df79\r\nClientRequestId: fbb7587c-356f-4e96-80b5-7a684069df79\r\n"` 
A screenshot of Azure permissions:
[I'm not allowed to embed images yet.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bt73r.jpg)
The scope is "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default", I tried changing it to "Calendars.ReadWrite.All Users.Read.All" but the error was a bad request, scope not allowed. 
Even with different AuthenticationProvider the resultis the same.

```
IConfidentialClientApplication app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(daemonConfig.ClientId)
                .WithAuthority(AzureCloudInstance.AzurePublic, daemonConfig.Tenant)
                .WithClientSecret(daemonConfig.ClientSecret)
                .Build();

IGraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(async (requestMessage) =>
            {
                var scopes = new string[] { daemonConfig.Scope };
                AuthenticationResult authRes = await app.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes).ExecuteAsync();
                requestMessage.Headers
                    .Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", authRes.AccessToken);
            }));

var meetingResponse = await graphClient.Users["User@Email.com"]
                .FindMeetingTimes(attendees, locContraint, timeConstraint, new Duration(new TimeSpan(0, 30, 0)), 5, true, true, 100)
                .Request()
                .Header("Prefer", "outlook.timezone=\"W. Europe Standard Time\"")
                .PostAsync();
```

However, the following function works properly:

```
public Task<User> GetMicrosoftUser(string mail)
        {
            return graphClient.Users[mail]
                .Request()
                .GetAsync();
        }
```

Update 1:
GetSchedule function is working properly

```
await graphClient.Users["user@email.com"].Calendar
                    .GetSchedule(schedules, end, start)
                    .Request()
                    .Header("Prefer", "outlook.timezone=\"W. Europe Standard Time\"")
                    .PostAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

The ***POST /users/{id|userPrincipalName}/findMeetingTimes*** is not supported with *application permissions* as in the [findMeetingTimes  permissions docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-findmeetingtimes?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions). If you must use application permissions then try [getSchedule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/calendar-getschedule?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) to see if it will work for you.

You can also consider raising a feature request for the support on the [MS365 Developer Platform Forum](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/idb-p/Microsoft365DeveloperPlatform)